# How to fix Jenkins script running on multinode network, curl commands in script do not work and output `Authorization Required`

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I have a 4 node network running and would like to execute curl commands on top of the running network. Running on my machine and ssh-ing on to 1 node is sufficient enough to complete the test however when moving the commands to a Jenkins script I get this response

```
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.13.6.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

OAuth is enabled on 1 of 4 machines. How does one solve this?

My network runs on aws nodes

```
    curl -X POST "http://<node1_IP>/bloc/v2.2/users/<account>/<address1>/send?resolve=true" -H "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -d "{ \"toAddress\": \"<address2>\", \"value\": \"1\", \"password\": \"<password>\", \"metadata\": null, \"txParams\": null}"
        transactionHash=$(curl -X POST "http://<node1_IP>:8080/bloc/v2.2/users/t1/<address1>/send?resolve=true" -H "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -d "{ \"toAddress\": \"<address2>\", \"value\": \"1\", \"password\": \"t1\", \"metadata\": null, \"txParams\": null}" | jq -r '.txResult' | jq -r '.transactionHash')
        echo "transactionHash: $transactionHash"
        transactionHash=$transactionHash
```

I expect the first one to return data in json format, and for the second curl I expect a string to be stored in the transactionHash.